# I need a advanced search block (by using views) on home page of site

Tags: views

I'm beginner in drupal.
I'm developing a site contains products that are displayed some product blocks by using views module on front page like **featured products** and **top rated products**.
Now, I also need to add a **advanced search block** (*by using views module*) on front page like I've attached **image** below. This search will only search from the one type of content named *product* and show another page.

How to add input field name titled, dropdown list, radio buttons and Search button while creating views block?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Drupal 7 you can create mentioned output via setting Filters and set the option "Expose this filter to the user"

Moreover, you can add checkbox using [BEF](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters)(Better Exposed Filters).

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: welcome..... :)